# How do I send an array to a Google Sheet range?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to transfer an array to a google sheet, but the code isn't working. (In debug mode I can see that my array is there, but 'setValues' isn't displaying any data to my sheet.)

Here's my code:

```
var cal_start = stp.getRange("B2").getValue(); // start date
var cal_end = stp.getRange("B3").getValue();  // end date
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(cal_start), new Date(cal_end));

// Cooper on StackOverflow provided this deduplication code... I have no idea how it works
var mylist=[];
var obj={eA:[]};
for(var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
  var key=events[i].getTitle() + events[i].getDescription();
  if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    obj[key]={title:events[i].getTitle(),description:events[i].getDescription(),guests:events[i].getGuestList().length, start:events[i].getStartTime(),id:events[i].getId(),copies:0};
    obj.eA.push(key);
  }else{
    obj[key].copies+=1; //count the copies
  }
}
for(var i=0;i<obj.eA.length;i++) {
  mylist.push(obj[obj.eA[i]]);
}

// Create a header row, and display the mylist array on a sheet called "all_meetings" (mtg)
mtg.clearContents(); 
var header = [["Event Title", "Event Description", "Guests", "Event Start", "ID", "Copies"]]
var range = mtg.getRange(1,1,1,6);
range.setValues(header);

// The header above appears on the sheet, but my array isn't showing up. There are no errors
var range2 = mtg.getRange(2,1,1,6);
range2.setValues([mylist]);
```

NOTE: The data in my array looks like this:

```
+0
+1
-2
     title "Title text"
     description "Description text"
     guests (number)
     start (date/time)
     id (number)
     copies (number)
+3
+4
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is a mismatch between the length of `mylist` and the width of `range2`.

You could try defining `range2` as:

```
var range2 = mtg.getRange(2,1,1, mylist.length);
```

If that doesn't solve it, try logging `mylist` to check its dimensions and matching it with the dimensions of `range2`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! When I first tried the code above I got an error about a mismatch. I fixed that, and now there are no more errors being generated. (There just isn't any data being sent to my sheet.)

I'm guessing that there is an issue with the deduplicated array. I'm pretty new to coding but I think my array is an array within an array. Do I perhaps need to iterate through each "row"?

Comment: Could you add a `Logger.log(mylist)` to the code and share a screenshot of what the logged value looks like? I could not understand your note on what the data array looks like.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand this correctly, `mylist` is an array of objects, each of those objects corresponds to a calendar event, and you want to set the values of each event in each row in the sheet.

If that's the case, you would have to iterate through each event in `mylist`, and for each event, retrieve each of the property values and write them in the corresponding sheet row, in its proper order. To achieve this, you can replace this:

```js
// The header above appears on the sheet, but my array isn't showing up. There are no errors
var range2 = mtg.getRange(2,1,1,6);
range2.setValues([mylist]);
```

For this:

```js
for (var j = 0; j < mylist.length; j++) { // Iterate through all events in mylist
  // Retrieve event property values, in order:
  var title = mylist[j].title;
  var description = mylist[j].description;
  var guests = mylist[j].guest;
  var start = mylist[j].start;
  var id = mylist[j].id;
  var copies = mylist[j].copies;
  var values = [title, description, guests, start, id, copies];
  mtg.getRange(j + 2, 1, 1, 6).setValues([values]); // Writes property values to the sheet row
}
```

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: I was thinking about this issue on my walk to work today and I sort of came to the same conclusion. I'll try it out this weekend and mark it as "answered" if your suggestion works. Thank you!